# How to use variable(list) generated in a function as input for next function?

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x

I have the following code

```
# Random Strategy Selection: ramdomly choose a strategy within each player's strategy profile for each game in the input list

def RandomStrategySelection():    # Return the vectors with the selected
     P = pool_of_games
     j=10    #number of iterations
     s=1    #current round
     random_strategy=[]    #combination of randomly chosen strategies for each player 
     random_pool=[]    #pool of selected random strategies for the input vector games
     rp=random_pool
     while s<=j:
         for game in range (0, len(P)):    
             p1=random.choice(P[game][0][0:3])    #random choice within p1(row)'s strategy profile
             p2=random.choice(P[game][0][4:8])    #random choice within p2(column)'s strategy profile
             random_strategy=[p1,p2]
             random_pool.append(random_strategy)
         s=s+1
     return(rp)

def FitnessEvaluation():         # Return the rank of fitness of all evaluated games
    for game in range (0,len(rp)):
        pf1=rp[game][0]
        pf2=rp[game][1]
        fitness=payoff1+payoff2
    return(fitness)


    #fitness: f(G)=(F(G)*j+s)/j - F(G)=pf1+pf2
```

**RandomStrategySelection** generates a list of objects, such as

```
[[0,2][3,1]]
```

**FitnessEvaluation** is supposed to use that list, but I cant get it running.  **FitnessEvaluation** doesn't seem to recognize the list created, even after I stored it in the **rp** variable. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You stored it in a local **rp** variable.  This is distinct from the local **rp** variable in **RandomStrategySelection**.

The standard way to handle this is to save the return value (in the calling program) and pass it to the next one, such as:

```
pool = RandomStrategySelection()
how_fit = FitnessEvaluation(pool)
```

... and give the second function a signature that declares the parameter:

```
FitnessEvaluation(rp):
    for game in range (0,len(rp)):
        ....
```

Comment: Hey, then in this case the how_fit in the first function is also considered as "assigned and never used". Where is it supposed to be added afterwards?

Comment: That depends on the calling program.  What do you do with that final result returned form **FitnessEvaluation**?  Since you didn't supply a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I don't have the semantics to tell you what to do with that.